# Install pre-built Caffe compatible with GPU (Cuda 9.0) on Ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, caffe, conda

I need to install a pre-built working version of Caffe-gpu on Ubuntu 16.04 because each time I try to compile it, I fail.
Let me know if I need to install a newer version of Ubuntu.

My cuda version is 9.0, I can import libraries of Caffe2 on my system.

I tried to install it within a virtual environment set by Conda, by running these commands :
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/caffe-gpu

But when I run this command within the virtual environment

```
python -c "import caffe"
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/*****/miniconda3/envs/cudapy2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver, NCCL, Timer
  File "/home/*****/miniconda3/envs/cudapy2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: /home/*****/miniconda3/envs/cudapy2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/caffe/../../../libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined symbol: _ZNK6google8protobuf7Message11GetTypeNameEv
```